# Why does zip() of list of lists output such?

Tags: python, list, zip

Let's take:

```
a = zip([[1,2],[2,3]])
```

where a is the zipped variable of list of lists [[1,2],[2,3]]
the output for `print(list(a))`is

```
[([1, 2],), ([2, 3],)]
```

meaning the zip was a tuple containing ([1, 2],), ([2, 3],)?
Why is that? For example, why is there a comma before both end parentheses of the tuple?

If someone could walk me through the computational steps I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The zip() function takes iterables (can be zero or more), aggregates them in a tuple, and return it."

Basically it mean that you can do sometime like that:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = ["h", "b", "s"]

for num, char in zip(list1, list2):
    print(num, char)

# output:
# 1 h
# 2 b
# 3 s
```

enter value: `[[1,2],[2,3]]`

first you zip the list: `([1, 2],), ([2, 3],)` or just make tuples to the values

if you just enter a one list:

```
a = zip([1,2,3,4,5,6])

print(list(a))  # [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

it make the values in the list a tuples. (, for make it a one value tuple)

and after that you make it a list: `[([1, 2],), ([2, 3],)]`

Comment: thank you for the EXTRA clarification. I forgot the comma defines a tuple when enclosed in parentheses. :D

Comment: `tuple("hi")` is something different.

Comment: "hi" is a string, which is a list of chars. It is should be "h" (a char) and not "hi" (a string).